# Finding class instances that satisfy specific criteria

Tags: c#, list, class

I am using this class:

```
class player
{
    public string name;
    public int rating;
}
```

and would like to access the `name` due to the `rating` that I have.  Something along the lines of: "Get the name of the player that has the rating 4", or whatever the rating may be.
There must be some sort of link between name and rating because they are in the same class, but I'm not sure how to exploit this. Also if there are class instances where two of them have the same rating, how would it affect this?

I have 2 lists, one of type 'player' which holds the class instances and one of type 'int' that holds the ratings that I will be searching for.

Comment: *Get the name of the player that has the rating '4'* I'm assuming you're working with a `List<Player>`?

Comment: I have a list of the ratings but they are of type int, not player

Comment: You ought to have a list of `player` instances to search in

Comment: Ok, then where are you holding all your players? Meaning, what exactly are you trying to search? It's currently ambiguous from your question.

Comment: sorry, I do have a list of players but the ratings that I wish to use to search for them are in a separate list of type int as I used them in an algorithm that needed them like this.

Comment: As a side note, you should generally avoid public data members. You may want to turn them into auto-properties. For example, `public string name { get; set; }`.

Answer (score 4):

To demonstrate how this works lets create a List of players:

```
List<player> players = new List<player>();
```

Then add a few test players to the list:

```
players.Add(new player() { name = "Test1", rating = 1 });
players.Add(new player() { name = "Test2", rating = 1 });
players.Add(new player() { name = "Test3", rating = 2 });
```

Now lets use Linq to access the data in the list and select all players with rating 2 and get the name from that one player:

```
var rating2Player = players.FirstOrDefault(x => x.rating == 2);
var playerName = rating2Player.name;
```

What this does, is it searches for all players inside the `players` list that have rating 2 and selects the first one (or NULL if none found)

Now lets select players with rating 1, as we have two of these and see what happens:

```
var rating1Players = players.Where(x => x.rating == 1);
```

`rating1Players` now contains a list of all player objects that have rating 1.

To get the name of a player simply do `.name` on the player instance you selected

Comment: nice answer, spotted a typo though: "select all players with rating 2" FirstOrDefault won't return all players with rating 2, guessing you meant "select the player with rating 2"?

Comment: @Jay that is intentional, as there is only 1 player with rating 2. This gives me directly the player object instead of a list containing the 1 player

Comment: @Rondex I understood it, just could be confusing as firstordefault will never return more than 1 player. nvm :)

Comment: Is there any way to delete the player class that contains this rating once it has been found? @Jay

Comment: To remove it from the list, just do `players.Remove(yourPlayer)`

Comment: @A-Lill please mark the most suiting answer to you with the green tick below the up and downvote button. This will officialy mark your quesiton as answered and future readers will find the correct answer more easily.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the instances of Player are in some kind of IEnumerable. Then what you need is `Where` or `FindAll`:

```
list.Where( x => x.rating == 4 );
```

The precise query depends on the information you're after, of course.

In your case, you have a list of ratings that you're after, and a list of names. You could simply iterate over that list:

```
foreach ( int currentRating in ratingList )
{
    var playersAtSameLevel = list.Where( x => x.rating == currentRating  );
     // Add code to add these players, or their names, to whatever data structure you are using to keep them.
 }
```

If you want all relevant players in a single collection, you could also look into creating a more complicated LINQ query using Join.

```
var result = from rating in ratings
             join player in players on rating equals player.rating 
             select player;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had a `List<player> playersList` 
You could look for the first element which meets the condition:

```
player playerRated4 = playersList.Find(x => x.rating == 4);
```

This above example will return the first player that has the rating of 4.

or a list of elements which meet your condition

```
List<player> playersListRated4 = playersList.FindAll(x => x.rating == 4);
```

This above example will return all players who have the rating of 4 as a list of players

Answer (score -3):

Try putting it into a dictionary,

```
Dictionary<int,Player> Players,
```

The player class can have all information like first name and last name, and the Int of the dictionary will be your rating, that way you can use the Dictionary (key-value pair) to get the player for a certain rating,

```
Player player;
if (Players.TryGetValue(4, out player)) // Returns true when a player with rating 4 has been found.
{
    Console.WriteLine(player.name); // the player object contains all the player data.
}
```

Comment: This solution is clearly wrong for two reasons: First, he mentoined there can be more than 1 player for a given rating, which is not possible to model with a dictionary. Second this results in redunant data, you would store the rating as a key ans still have the rating inside the players object

Comment: Provided with the details of the question, the Dictionary is not a well-suited data structure for the solution and as RononDex motioned is redundant.  Once the user tries to add an existing Key the Dictionary he will get an ArgumentException stating that "the An element with the same key already exists in the Dictionary<TKey, TValue>." Making the solution incorrect